# Mockito-Kotlin exception: UnfinishedStubbingException

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing, mockito-kotlin

I am writing a BDD test with Cucumber and mockito_kotlin.
The verify function is like:

```
@Then("there shouldn't be any coockie eaten.")
fun there_shouldnt_be_any_coockie_eaten() {
    verify(mockCoockie, never()).eatGoodCookie()(any(), any())
}
```

ICookie interface:

```
interface ICookie {
    val cookieSauce: Sauce?
    fun eatGoodCookie(): ListenableFuture<GetCookieListResult>
    fun eatBadCookie(): ListenableFuture<GetCookieListResult>
    //...
}
```

My mockCookie in test class:

```
private val mockCookie = mock<ICookie> {
    on { cookieSauce }.thenReturn(mock()) ------- Line 35
    on { eatGoodCookie(any(), any()) }
        .thenReturn(Futures.immediateFuture(GetCookieListResult().apply {
            appList = emptyArray()
        })).thenReturn(Futures.immediateFuture(GetCookieListResult().apply {
            appList = arrayOf(theOnlyCookieCatalog)
        }))
    //...
}
```

But I encountered these error:

**org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.MockitoKt.whenever(Mockito.kt:253)**

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed

I do not know I against which tule.
Did someone encounter similar problem?

The version of related tools are:

testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.2.4'
testImplementation 'com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0'
testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'

Comment: you're verifying `eaten()` , but in mocking part I can only see `eatGoodCookie ()` ?

Comment: @moozg Oops, I have edited the test function. Thanks!

Comment: should I add it as an answer?

Comment: @moozg It was just my typo QQ. The problem is still there. Still big thanks to you!

Comment: 1. then there's one more typo - in first snippet - `mockCoockie`. 
2. And the interface methods have no params? 
3. in which line exactly (mapped to your snippets) the error is reported? 
4. Have you tried removing one of `thenReturn()` part for `eatGoodCookie`? Does it work then?

Comment: @moozg The error is reported on Line 35. Remove the second thenReturn() is useless.